# Unable to implement check in my integration, getting 'map undefined' for create method of checks

Tags: github, github-api, probot, github-app

I am trying to implement Checks into my GitHub app. My App is built with probot.

I am just not able to implement the checks. I have tried going through the documentation which demonstrate ruby example that includes several different setups(not sure if required with probot).
I just got confused with the example there.

Below is the code that resides in my index.js :

```
app.on('check_suite.requested', async context =>{
      console.log('************------------ check suite requested')
      await context.github.checks.create({
        mediaType:'application/vnd.github.antiope-preview+json',
        name : 'test-check-1',
        head_sha: context.payload.check_suite.after,
        conclusion: "success"
      })
  })
```

I get below error

```
 ERROR probot: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

The error log complains about index.js:24:35, which is precisely the `create`method in the line `await context.github.checks.create`

Is the above code sufficient to create the check **test-check-1** or do I need to take care of other things too. I already have the **"Required status checks to pass before merging"** option enabled under the branch protection settings of my repo.
And that section displays **Sorry, we couldn’t find any status checks in the last week for this repository.**

Not sure how to connect everything.

**EDIT 1 : START**

Below is the code after including the required params as suggested by @OscarDOM :--

```
app.on('check_suite.requested', async context =>{
      console.log('*****check suite requested*****')
      context.github.checks.create({
        owner:context.payload.repository.owner,
        repo:context.payload.repository.name,
        mediaType:'application/vnd.github.antiope-preview+json',
        name : 'test-check-1',
        head_sha: context.payload.check_suite.after,
        conclusion: "success"
      })
  })
```

Unfortunately, I still get the same error at exact same line and column.

**EDIT 1 : END**

**EDIT 2 : START**

Below is the final working code after including corrections for the mediaType parameter :

Please note there was one more mistake I had to correct and that is the value owner param. The correct way is to specify context.payload.repository.owner.login and this was something I had recently learnt from [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61202144/error-event-not-found-when-triggering-event-from-another-event-probot-app-bu)

```
app.on('check_suite.requested', async context =>{
      console.log('*****check suite requested*****')
      context.github.checks.create({
        owner:context.payload.repository.owner.login,
        repo:context.payload.repository.name,
        mediaType: { previews: ['antiope']},
        name : 'test-check-1',
        head_sha: context.payload.check_suite.after,
        conclusion: "success"
      })
  })
```

**EDIT 2 : END**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible you need to pass the owner and the repository to `context.github.checks.create()` method? I think they are required properties: https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v17#checks

Also, make sure the Github App has the following permissions: `checks:write`(https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#checkrunevent)

---

Also, checking your code snippet, seems that you are not using the `mediaType` properly. If you check the type definition, mediaType has the following structure:

```js
mediaTypes: {
   format?: string,
   previews?: string[]
}
```

Reference here: https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v17#previews

Can you try it with this?

```js
app.on('check_suite.requested', async context =>{
        console.log('************------------ check suite requested')
        await context.github.checks.create({
            owner: '<YOUR_ORGANIZATION>',
            repo: '<YOUR_REPO>',
            mediaType: { previews: ['antiope']},
            name : 'test-check-1',
            head_sha: context.payload.check_suite.after,
            conclusion: "success"
        })
    })
```

---

As a general feedback, I suggest you to try TypeScript, these issues would have been spotted using it :)

Comment: Of course.I'll have to make it possible. :) If its says the params are reqd, then there's no escaping. I feel so dumb to have missed it. But I did provide the checks write permission. I will pass those reqd parameters and share my findings with you. Thank you so much @OscarDOM

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick edited response with a possible missing change you need to apply :)

Comment: Ok. I think I did exactly same.But that never worked for me. I will edit my OP and under section EDIT 1 I'll provide the changes I made to my code after your first suggestion. I think the only difference is the way of specifying the mediaType. Will try with that too.But please do check the  EDIT and let me know if that's fine

Comment: The rest looks good but without the mediaType fix, you want be able to communicate to the API. Let us know how it looks after your try

Comment: This worked. Thanks a ton. :) I can find them in the checks tab. There was one extra thing I had to take care of, i.e.owner.login instead of just owner.