# Probot check-js pull request

Tags: github-app, github-check-run

I'm building a code-review app for github using nodeJS (ProBot)

I'm trying to get the pull_request data out of the check_suite that was created in order to get the relevant files and run my tests but the context.payload.pull_request is empty.

i tried also listening to the event pull_request.created, there I have the data that I need but the context.github.checks.update() / context.github.checks.create() does not update the status of the check and and stays in_progress forever.

here is my code :

```
module.exports = app => {
app.on([
'check_suite.requested',
'check_run',
'pull_request.opened', 
], check)
async function check (context) {
const startTime = new Date()

if (context.payload.check_suite) {
  const { head_branch: headBranch, head_sha: headSha } = context.payload.check_suite

   return context.github.checks.create(context.repo({
    name: 'SoftaCheck',
    head_branch: headBranch,
    head_sha: headSha,
    status: 'in_progress',
    started_at: startTime,
  }))
}

const payload =  {head_branch: context.payload.pull_request? context.payload.pull_request.base.ref : context.payload.check_run.pull_requests[0].base.ref ,head_sha : context.payload.pull_request? context.payload.pull_request.base.sha : context.payload.check_run.pull_requests[0].base.sha }

const { head_branch, head_sha } = payload

if (context.payload.pull_request) {
    
   //some async code here in order to decide conclusion...

   context.github.checks.create(context.repo({
     name: 'SoftaCheck',
     head_branch,
     head_sha,
     status: 'completed',
     conclusion:'success'
     started_at: startTime,
   }))

}
```

}

// For more information on building apps:
// https://probot.github.io/docs/

// To get your app running against GitHub, see:
// https://probot.github.io/docs/development/
}

Comment: Hello @H.Epstein, have you found a good solution / example / repo to reference for your question? Trying to do something similar, their documentation is both good and bad

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are trying to implement `check.create` method. That method takes in several parameters(**some mandatory, some optional**), but you are passing in a repo object. You should be passing in the repo name instead.

Few things to note:

- your GitHub App must have [`check:write` permission](https://developer.github.com/v3/checks/runs/#create-a-check-run:%7E:text=permission%20to%20create%20check%20runs)
- Also, make sure your `checks.create` method has the [required properties](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#checks-create)(properties which are mandatory). For instance, **owner**  property is missing in your case.

Earlier I had run into [somewhat similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61810089/unable-to-implement-check-in-my-integration-getting-map-undefined-for-create).